# crcmod installed, but gsutil shows "compiled crcmod: False"

Tags: centos6, python, google-cloud-platform

I suspect this is something to do with the fact that I'm on CentOS 6.9 and have had to install SCL Python 2.7 so as not to interfere with the default Python 2.6 install.

I've been through the steps at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CRC32CandInstallingcrcmod though, and didn't get any errors.

`gsutil ver -l` though, still shows

`compiled crcmod: False`

How can I fix this?

I have it working on another (CentOS 7) box.  A difference I've noticed is that on the CentOS 7 box, the crcmod files are in `lib64`, whereas on the CentOS 6 box, the crcmod files are in `lib`.  Both boxes are 64bit, and Python 2.7 is running 64bit on both systems (checked with `print struct.calcsize("P") * 8`)

So I think the Centos6 box has somehow installed 32bit crcmod instead of 64bit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to setup crcmod on CentOS 6 instance by using the following script:

```
$ nano p.sh
```

--- script ---

```
yum groupinstall -y "Development tools"
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel 
-y
cd /tmp
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/Python-2.7.15.tgz
tar xf Python-2.7.15.tgz
cd Python-2.7.15
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make altinstall
cp -a /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/google_compute_engine/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_compute_engine/
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python2.7 get-pip.py
ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/bin/pip2.7
```

----- End of script -----

```
$ sudo chmod +x p.sh
$ sudo ./p.sh

$ export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7   #make it as a permanent change

$ sudo yum install gcc python-devel python-setuptools redhat-rpm-config
$ sudo pip2.7 install -U crcmod

$ gsutil version -l
>> compiled crcmod: True
```